# How can I catch the error when trying to not print empty fields in FormView ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, nullreferenceexception, formview

I'm trying to build an address in FormView that is dependent from a GridView which has a list of contact names.

When I click the select button next to bills name from the GridView, it shows me bills addresses in the FormView.  When I click it a second time when bill is already selected, it throws a NullReferenceException error.

I have the following fields:  address_line_1, address_line_2, address_line_3

I have tried to build the code so that it doesn't generate wasted line of whitespace if the field is empty or contains a null.

```
<asp:FormView ID="addressDetails" runat="server" DataSourceID="ADetails" DataKeyNames="address_id" AllowPaging="true" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <% If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(addressDetails.DataItem("address_line_1").ToString()) Then%>
            <asp:Label ID="lblAddressLine1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("address_line_1") %>' /><br />
        <%  End If%>
        <% If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(addressDetails.DataItem("address_line_2").ToString()) Then%>
            <asp:Label ID="lblAddressLine2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("address_line_2") %>' /><br />
        <%  End If%>
        <% If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(addressDetails.DataItem("address_line_3").ToString()) Then%>
            <asp:Label ID="lblAddressLine3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("address_line_3") %>' /><br />
        <%  End If%>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

The exception I get is "NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code" at line:

```
<% If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(addressDetails.DataItem("address_line_1").ToString()) Then%>
```

Does anyone know why it works first time but not the second?

Comment: And this is partially why I now develop in MVC and not WebForms. Building and debugging Gridviews and Listviews etc are a waste of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up re-phasing a big chunk of my page and removed the If statements within the aspx page.